# Creating categories SQL

Tags: sql, toad

I'm sure there is an easy way to do this, but I'm lost. I've tried `Case` and `IF` statements, but still nothing.
I've got two tables both holding descriptive text fields. I need to create a link that says,

```
IF I.desc='Door' then P.desc IN ('Door', 'Hinge','Wood Frame')
ELSE IF I.desc='Cabinet' then P.desc IN ('Door','Hinge','knob','drawer').
```

Not exactly what my descriptions are, but it's an example of what I need to link. Unique `I.desc` has to pull multiple `P.desc` that overlap into other unique `I.desc1`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please share the ddl of table, sample data, exlected output and query that you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

To me, it looks as if you needed the **third** table which would contain **pairs** of valid combinations. Something like this (Oracle-ish code; you didn't specify which database you use, but it is a simple matter to populate such a table with some data):

```
create table pairs (i_desc, p_desc) as
   select 'Door'   , 'Hinge'      from dual union all
   select 'Door'   , 'Wood Frame' from dual union all
   select 'Cabinet', 'Door'       from dual union all
   select 'Cabinet', 'Hinge'      from dual union all
   select 'Cabinet', 'Drawer'     from dual;
```

It is easy to maintain it; if new elements appear, you'd just insert a new row, e.g.

```
insert into pairs (i_desc, p_desc) values ('Cabinet', 'Knob');
```

Query you'd then use would join these 3 tables as

```
select ...
from i_table i join pairs r   on i.desc = r.i_desc
               join p_table p on p.desc = r.p_desc
where ...
```